# Structuring a multi-executable Go project

Tags: go, aws-lambda, structure, microservices, go-modules

I am trying to build a micro-services architecture project in Go. I am currently using Go 1.11 which supports modules, so I put my root directory in an arbitrary chosen directory, outside of `GOPATH`.

If I am getting the micro-services architecture concepts right, although my microservices need to be independent, they can share dependencies (and I don't see another way to do stuff, is it?)

Below is my directory structure:

```
.
├── go.mod
├── lambda
│   └── account_create
│       └── main.go
├── readme.md
└── types
    ├── account.go
    ├── location.go
    ├── order.go
    ├── pricing.go
    ├── product.go
    └── types.go
```

Now the behavior I expected was to be able to run `go build lambda/account_create` and get an executable with that functionality so I can supply it to the respective AWS Lambda function.

However, when I run the command, I get:

```
can't load package: package lambda/account_create: unknown import path "lambda/account_create": cannot find module providing package lambda/account_create
```

Please explain me why this does not work and give me some advice on how a project like this should look.

Thank you very much!

**Edit** Here is my `lambda/account_create/main.go` file contents:

```
package account_create

import (
    "fmt"
    "roasted.ro/pkg/types"
)

func main() {
    account := types.UserAccount{Name: "Victor"}
    fmt.Printf("Welcome %s", account.Name)
}
```

Comment: Pass the fully qualified import path (which starts with the module name), or `./lambda/account_create` (note the leading `./`).

Comment: @Peter it does not complain anymore but there is no executable generated.

Comment: Why downvote? I really am trying to find a good structure for such a project and I am sure others would be interested too.

Comment: That's no so easy to develop multi-module projects sharing common code parts with Golang, I had some requests from users of my Maven golang wrapper tool (Maven provides great way to build multi-module applications) and I have made some example of Maven multi-module Golang project, if you want try such approach, just install Maven and build project skeleton from architype as written in https://github.com/raydac/mvn-golang-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the latter part of your question (as the first half is more about preference), you need to do:

```
go build ./lambda/account_create
```

Notice the `./`. `go build` takes in a package name or a path. If you don't prepend the path with a `./`, it assumes you are giving it a package name.

**Edit**: the package has to be `main` if you want an executable. According to the [docs](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#PackageNames), you always have to use `package main` for projects that build an executable:

> Executable commands must always use `package main`.

**Edit**: I'll add some opinions on layout:

Consider which parts of your project are exported to other go projects. Meaning someone could import your package and expect to gain value and not have their code break when yours changes.

That should be either in a `github.com/you/pkg/somepath` package or just `github.com/you/somepath`.

Anything else (other than main packages) should be under a `/internal` package.

I typically make a `/cmd/myexecurable1`  `/cmd/myexecurable2` and so forth for each executable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I replied to Peter’s comment on the question saying that the command is indeed returning no error however no executable seems to be created.

Comment: Yes. It produces an executable without the “x” permission attached to it (which is the first strange thing) and if I attach that permission, it gives a strange error when run.

Comment: Do you have a main function and is it in the main package?

Comment: Which main package are we referring to? The one in root or the one in `lambda/account_create`?

Comment: The main.go in lambda/account_create

Comment: Change the package to main

Comment: Please add some advice for my first question regarding the structure itself if you can! Thanks!

Comment: Haha I'll throw in some opinions

Comment: I added some stuff about layout